# UIView block animation move view left to right and back to left

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

I wan't to animate a view that's shaped as an arrow, and I want it to animate from left to right, left to right and so on..

This code below is not working, I'm guessing I need a path, but don't know how to do that in a UIView block animation.

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    controller.view.frame = frame1;
    controller.view.frame = frame2;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` option, try the code below:

```
UIView * testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 100.0f, 300.0f, 200.0f)];
[testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.view addSubview:testView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     [testView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, 300.0f, 200.0f)];
                 }
                 completion:nil];

[testView release];
```

It'll repeat move from right to left, left to right, ... smoothly.

Comment: your animation works well when `TestView` is added on `ViewController`...but not when it is added on a another `View`..if possible plz help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148239/animating-subviews-left-right-left

Comment: Hi @CodeJack , it does work even on another View, what you have to modify is only to replace `[self.view addSubview:testView];` to `[self addSubview:testView];`. That's all. I've tested it & it works perfect. ;)

Comment: @Kjuly My UIView have three UIButton. This button not remove while animate view. It's still there. How to move all subview while UIView animate

Comment: @Thangavel just add your buttons on the view as subviews. :) For the answer as an e.g., add these buttons on `testView`.

Comment: @Kjuly I added button is subview to my view. My animate view is top to buttom. I set frame to UIView is         [_dropLocationView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 140.0f, 320.0f, 0.0f)];
and set frame to [_dropLocationView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 140.0f, 320, 120.0f)]; while animate. Button is not moved with view while animate.

Comment: @Thangavel the params you offered means to animate the view height, not the position. What you need to do is change the value of origin.y. Try  from `(0.0f, 140.0f, 320.0f, 120.0f)` to `(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 120.0f)`. I suggest you to take a look at the doc of `CGRectMake`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `frame1` is the starting position and `frame2` is the end position before repeat.

The problem is that the animation is calculated at the end of the runloop therefore the `frame1` is ignored and the view is simply moved to `frame2`. If you move the setting of `frame1` outside of the block then it should work fine. If you want the animation to play back and forward you will need to make it `autoreverse` with `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse`