# Animating subviews left-right-left

Tags: iphone, animation

I want to create a view like the QuickActionBar in Android , which when clicked on a button in top left corner opens  simply , but it subviews appears as if they are coming from Right , hit on the left wall , and rebounded back , and then stationed . 
view is appearing , but i am unable to animate the subviews..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAKeyframeAnimation looks right for your problem. I have written this animation function before for a label sliding across screen. I updated xValues slightly for your purposes but most probably you will have to play with them. Also after hitting the wall you might want to play with scale.y value you can easily integrate that into keyframe animation.

```
+ (void) slideAcrossScreen:(UIView *) view Duration:(CGFloat) duration FromLeft:(BOOL) fromLeft
{
    //This is to make it work with both left-right-left and right-left-right anims.
    CGFloat slideLength = fromLeft ? -view.frame.origin.x : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - (view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.size.width);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];

    NSArray *xValues =
              @[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:view.bounds.origin.x],
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:view.bounds.origin.x + 10 * slideLength / 10],
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:view.bounds.origin.x + 10 * slideLength / 10],
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:view.bounds.origin.x + 9 * slideLength / 10]];

    [anim setValues:xValues];

    NSArray *timeFrames = 
              @[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.85],
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9],
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];

    [anim setKeyTimes:timeFrames];
    [anim setDuration:duration];
    [anim setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [anim setRemovedOnCompletion:FALSE];

    [view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"slide"];
}
```

Comment: why is the `timesFrames` contains no values between 0.0 and 0.85 ??

Comment: you can edit them as you like 0.85 is the time it hits the wall. Times are attached to xValues defined above, so at time 0.0 it will be in the initial pos, then until 0.85 it will slide at a fixed speed till it hits the wall.

Answer (score 0):

I just spend 15 minuts in order to resolve your trouble as animating view is always interesting part. So here is snippet, you pass your `view` to it and it'll animate that. Ofcourse you can add some more to it if you want.

```
+ (void) animateView : (UIView *) view{
    __block CGRect frame = view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = - 320;
    [view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f animations:^{
        frame.origin.x = 10.0f;
        frame.size.width = 310.0f;
        [view setFrame:frame];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
                frame.size.width = 320.0f;
                [view setFrame:frame];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Cheers.